# How to disable innodb in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I added the line 'skip_innodb' in my.cnf file to disable innodb and restarted the mysqld. But,It is not effecting in database. Is there any alternative solutions ?

Comment: It is no longer possible starting in 5.7.5. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-turning-off.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `skip-innodb` under `[mysqld]` in `my.cnf` and then `restart` the MySQL server

See mysql log file for the success using `tail -100 log_file_name_with_full_path`

Verify using following query:

```
SHOW ENGINES;
```

Comment: See the below lines which is in my.cnf.But It is not working.
[mysqld_safe]
default-storage-engine = MYISAM
skip-innodb. Show engines query shows that innodb is 'YES'

Comment: skip-innodb must be inside [mysql] section of your my.cnf file

Answer (score 35):

If you are using MySql 5.5 or above,

```
ignore-builtin-innodb
```

and

```
default-storage-engine = myisam
```

under

```
[mysqld]
```

in  `/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: I got this error - Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
error: Found option without preceding group in config file: /etc/my.cnf at line: 1

Comment: [mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
# to do so, uncomment this line:
# symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
ignore-builtin-innodb
default-storage-engine = myisam
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Comment: `[Warning] ignore-builtin-innodb is deprecated and will be removed in future releases.`

Comment: As of MySQL 5.5 and above, instead of using `ignore-builtin-innodb`, use either `innodb=OFF` or `skip-innodb` and then follow it with `default-storage-engine = myisam`.

See: [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html) and [Todd's MySQL Blog](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2012/08/31/deprecated-in-mysql-5-6-ignore_builtin_innodb/)

Comment: This is the only solution work it should marked as best answer

Comment: Should be written as answer for MariaDB

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
innodb=OFF
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
```

MyISAM is just a example you can choose wathever you want there
You can read more here http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1052143

Answer (score 7):

### For `mysql 5.6+`

Iv'e had difficulties trying the apply the other answers. 
This is what i found best with `mysql 5.6.19`

**1) edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`**

**-- IMPORTANT** - place these values **under `[mysqld]`**

```
# ... other settings
[mysqld]

innodb=OFF
loose-innodb-trx=0
loose-innodb-locks=0
loose-innodb-lock-waits=0
loose-innodb-cmp=0
loose-innodb-cmp-per-index=0
loose-innodb-cmp-per-index-reset=0
loose-innodb-cmp-reset=0
loose-innodb-cmpmem=0
loose-innodb-cmpmem-reset=0
loose-innodb-buffer-page=0
loose-innodb-buffer-page-lru=0
loose-innodb-buffer-pool-stats=0
loose-innodb-metrics=0
loose-innodb-ft-default-stopword=0
loose-innodb-ft-inserted=0
loose-innodb-ft-deleted=0
loose-innodb-ft-being-deleted=0
loose-innodb-ft-config=0
loose-innodb-ft-index-cache=0
loose-innodb-ft-index-table=0
loose-innodb-sys-tables=0
loose-innodb-sys-tablestats=0
loose-innodb-sys-indexes=0
loose-innodb-sys-columns=0
loose-innodb-sys-fields=0
loose-innodb-sys-foreign=0
loose-innodb-sys-foreign-cols=0

default-storage-engine=MyISAM
default_tmp_storage_engine=MyISAM

# ...
```

**2) restart mysql**

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

*Source: [MySQL docs - 14.1.3 Turning Off InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-turning-off.html)*

---

## What about migration?

if you want to **migrate your existing database** from `InnoDB` to `MyISAM`, the above as-is **does not effect existing tables** (and will give you runtime errors).

### Solution

there is a utility called `mysqldump` uses store the existing database tables  + data into file (SQL script)

#### 1) backup

```
mysqldump -u [user] -p[pass] [database name] > /tmp/backup.sql
```

#### 2) change `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` as shown above

```
nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf

# ...
[mysqld]

innodb=OFF
loose-innodb-trx=0
loose-innodb-locks=0
# ...
```

#### 3) restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

#### 4) reload data from 1st step

```
mysql -u [user] -p[pass] [database name] < /tmp/backup.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL 5.5+ the required configuration fragment would be as follows

```
[mysqld]
skip-innodb
default-storage-engine = myisam
```