# AJAX HTTP error SQLSTATE[42000]:Syntax error

Tags: php, sql, ajax, drupal, wampserver

i am try to install drupal distribution [campaigion](http://www.campaignion.org) on my local WAMP server. But during installation it always give AJAX HTTP error.

[image]

I contact support team of campaigion but no reponse.How to cope this one.

Comment: I don't know drupal, but the errors details is at the bottom of you post: `Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`. I did a quick google: https://www.drupal.org/node/982980

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

If you see [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-index.html):

> Prefix support and lengths of prefixes (where supported) are storage
>   engine dependent. For example, a prefix can be up to 1000 bytes long
>   for MyISAM tables, and 767 bytes for InnoDB tables.

I [turned off](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-turning-off.html) InnoDB:

You could find my.ini in WAMP server in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538045/where-is-the-ini-file-for-wamp-server-for-mysql-workbench-integration):

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\my.ini
```

Comment: in my.ini file of mysql where i edit the value.there is no value that match 767 bytes

Comment: You can´t change the 767 bytes. You must turn off InnoDB because InnoDB use 767bytes. The easiest way that i have founded is in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772611/how-to-disable-innodb-in-mysql. Search [mysqld] in your my.ini and add:
skip-innodb

default-storage-engine = myisam