# WAMP Server stays offline. MySQL service not starting "could not start the wampmysqld64 service - error 1067"

Tags: mysql, wamp, innodb

I have spent hours trying to get the server running (for the first time), trying many solutions posted online, but to no success.

First time install (Win 7 x64), light remains orage (server offline). If I look at service, the start/resume service remains green:

[image]

If I go in services and try start `wampmysqld64` service I get this error message:

[image]

Here is the Event Viewer Application log (the WAMP mysql log is empty):

```
Error   11/09/2015 09:04:22 MySQL   100 None Aborting
Error   11/09/2015 09:04:22 MySQL   100 None Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
Error   11/09/2015 09:04:22 MySQL   100 None Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
Error   11/09/2015 09:04:22 MySQL   100 None Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
Error   11/09/2015 09:04:22 MySQL   100 None InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
Error   11/09/2015 09:04:22 MySQL   100 None InnoDB: space header page consists of zero bytes in data file .\ibdata1
Warning 11/09/2015 09:04:22 MySQL   100 None InnoDB: Doublewrite does not have page_no=0 of space: 0
```

I haven't removed/deleted any files, but I did install WAMP server on my `D` drive (OS on `C`) due to space limitations).

Comment: @Mecanik I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772611/how-to-disable-innodb-in-mysql) but did not make a difference

Comment: I see, then why not use Winginx? Xammp and Lammp and Wammp from my opinion is crap...

Comment: @Mecanik I haven't used any of the 3 but a google search pointed me to WAMP. What is it that you like about Winginx? If I don't find a solution, that will be go to that

Comment: WAMP is a less stable platform. I would suggest XAMP over WAMP. It is light compared to wamp-server and much stable than WAMP.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Installing WAMPServer on the D: drive is just fine.

Possibly somehow these files have been corrupted so try deleting them.

Stop WAMPServer

Delete these files, as this is an initial install they will not have any data in them and the restart of WAMPServer should cause MYSQL to re-create them.

```
\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\ib_logfile0
\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\ib_logfile1
\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\data\ibdata1
```

*Now for a little bug fix:* Edit `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\my.ini`
Find the section marker `[wampmysqld]` and change it to `[wampmysqld64]`

Save `my.ini`

Restart WAMPServer

Also if you are a little short of memory adding this parameter to the `my.ini` file inside the `[wampmysqld64]` will reduce the MYSQL memory requirement. Later versions of MYSQL seem to use a hugh amounts of memory ( half a gig ) lots of which is the `table_definition_cache` for MYISAM files, this will reduce it to something sensible and not effect your use of MYISAM files.

```
[wampmysqld64]
table_definition_cache = 600
```

Comment: +1 - I owe you a keg of beer! This works, thank you so much! Good to know about the hungry memory usage as well, that will be useful on another of my machines! Thanks again!

Comment: Mmmmm I look forward to the beer, best thankyou I have ever had on SO. _Friday Night is Party Night_

Comment: it really was turning out to be a write-off day (one of my IDEs also crashed  today), but everything is solved now :). I did actually think it was a corrupt file, but after the 3rd consecutive install attempt, I didn't think it would be that. Anyway, I'll salute you with my Leffe tonight. *Friday Night is Party Night*

Comment: Well in that case **Prost**

Comment: All database will remain same as it was after this steps ?

Comment: Thank you!  After half the day looking for a solution and not finding anything that worked, deleting those three files worked. You are a king.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just had to: edit `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\my.ini` and find the section `[wampmysqld]` and change it to `[wampmysqld64]`.

Then I restarted mysql and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

For me, I realised that I had another MySQL program (from Oracle) installed that was causing a common port-use conflict. Uninstall/disable MySQL server/workbench and other MySQL programs then restart WAMP. This might solve the problem, it worked for me.

I also uninstalled and deleted an old version of WAMP before installing the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

WAMP is a less stable platform. I would suggest XAMPP over WAMP.
It is light compared to wamp-server and much stable than WAMP.

Benefits -

XAMPP is more powerful and resource taking than WAMP.
WAMP provides support for MySQL and PHP.
XAMPP provides support for MYSQL, PHP and PERL

XAMPP also has SSL feature while WAMP doesn't.
If your applications need to deal with native web apps only, Go for WAMP. If you need advanced features as stated above, go for XAMPP.

As of priority, you cant run both together with default installation as XAMPP gets a higher priority and it takes up ports. So WAMP can't be run in parallel with XAMPP.

Comment: Most of this is unfortunately completely wrong. WAMPServer and XAMPP are basically the same thing, other than XAMPP has Perl as part of it, but nothing to stop you installing that yourself if its required. WAMPServer now has mariaDB and MySQL, while XAMPP went with only mariaDB. WAMPServer can easily switch between versions of Apache/MySQL/mariaDB/PHP/phpMyAdmin while XAMPP comes with only one version of each of these and no MySQL.

Answer (score -2):

1. If mysql service is not starting open `my.ini` file located at `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql[version]\my.ini`
2. Change port number to 3305 at 3 location:

Here:

```
#password   = your_password
port        = 3305
socket      = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Here:

```
\# The MySQL server
[wampmysqld]
port        = 3305
```

And here:

```
[mysqld]
port=3305
```

3. Now go to `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin[version]`, find `config.inc.php` and change this line:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
```

to this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3305';
```

(3305 being the port you selected previously).

Those steps should get your MySQL running.