# Wamp Server Error [Local Server - 2 of 3 services running]

Tags: mysql, windows-services, wamp, wampserver

I am new to wamp servers and trying to install wampServer 3.1.0 on my windows 10 machine .

Somehow it is not installed properly and is having configuration error .

At present "Wamp server is still in orange state and is throwing the error"

> 2 of 3 services running

As of my understanding either of Apache,MySQl orPHP is not working .
On further investigation I found that Apache is ok.
But on running mysql.exe(C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin) it is throwing :

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'
>   (10061)

which lands me to [SO-32519474](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519474/wamp-server-stays-offline-mysql-service-not-starting-could-not-start-the-wampm#) ,
I tried following the steps ,but it looks good to me in my case .
On further searching I find that wampmysqld64 is stopped in the services.
when I am trying to restart it I am getting the error 
[image]

I am stuck up here and have no further clue how to get it fixed

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The 3 services are Apache(`wampapache64`) MySQL(`wampmysqld64`) and MariaDB('wampmariadb64') PHP is not run as a service in WAMPServer.

Comment: My initial guess would be that you have another MySQL Server installed on this PC and that is started automatically and therefore has grabbed port 3306. Check for another installation of MySQL

Comment: Thanks for informing the three  services.

Comment: First check the mysql error log in `\wamp64\logs` if that does not help, check the `Windows Event Log` for error messages from `MYSQL`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you. Your comment here sorted me out. I forgot I had installed MySQL from oracle on my PC a few months back. Once I uninstalled that I "restarted all services" in WAMP and the logo is now green and I can log in to phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got to this [SOI=35670755](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670755/the-mysql-service-on-local-computer-started-and-then-stopped) and executed this command

> mysqld --initialize

inside (C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\bin)

this fixed my issue.

If in case you still have issues refer to this post 
[Wamp Server Error [Local Server - 2 of 3 services running]](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,149937)

**Edit:

> mysqld --initialize

may not be a great solution ,its kind of patch work.
It leads to issues with username and password.
The best way to install xampp is completely described in the following links

[Wamp Server Error [Local Server - 2 of 3 services running]](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,149937)
&
[Error While Logging into MYSQL](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,149962)

Comment: Based on doing this, I would uninstall WAMPServer and then reinstall it. After checking that you do not have another MySQL Server installed on this PC

Comment: @ RiggsFolly ,Hello ,Yeah I did it like that only ,completely uninstalled wampp and installed again.
I dint checked another instance of MYSQL though ,I am sure I never installed it :)
But thanks for letting us know ,another possible conflicting situation.

Comment: MySQL can come as part of other applications, you may not realise its there. Check in the Services snapin for a service called `mysql`

Comment: Thanks for the help it solved my problem too the icon is geen now but I still cannot login to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ with selected mysql options

Comment: I couldn't see any error but the icon was not changing its color into green after icon got green localhost/phpmyadmin is not getting logged in with username and blank password when select mysql but mardiadb was ok, so what I just uninstalled vcredist_x64 2012 and install vc_redistx64vc14 2015 and I have uninstalled wamp and reinstalled wamp everything is working fine.

Answer (score 20):

In my case was the Apache Service.

1. So I clicked the Wamp icon, then Apache > Service administration 'wampapache64' > Install Service.
2. Then again Wamp icon, then Apache > Service administration 'wampapache64' > Start Service.
3. And finally Wamp icon > Restart All Services.

Comment: This did fix my issue but I see php code instead of localhost page (only in Chrome). If I change navigator path inside wampmanager.conf file to edge or IE, it works fine

This was after a full re-install of my wamp where I had the same issues but more because when I enabled or disabled/commented out mime_module modules/mod_mime.so 

Not sure if the two are related but at least it works in Edge

Answer (score 6):

I found that WAMP can create a configuration report which details where problems lie.

Right-click on the WAMP icon, then Tools, then Create Wampserver Configuration Report (near the bottom). WAMP then opens and closes several cmd windows in generating the configuration report (wampConfReport.txt in the wamp directory).

Then again right-click on the WAMP icon, then Tools, then Wampserver Configuration Report. This will open the configuration report in your default text editor, and you can look through it to find what the problem is.

In my case I had another mysqld process listening on the port, and the report included the lines:

```
Your port 3307 is used by a processus with PID = 3132
The processus of PID 3132 is 'mysqld.exe' Session: Services
The service of PID 3132 for 'mysqld.exe' is 'MySQL57'
*** ERROR *** This service IS NOT from Wampserver - Should be: 'wampmysqld64' or 'wampmariadb64'
```

So after killing the process with PID 3132 and restarting WAMP everything worked ok.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue , related to MYSQL , If in your system mysql was there, later you installed WAMP then again one MYSQL will install as WAMP package, default port for MYSQL is 3306 , So in both mysql the port will be 3306, which is a port conflict, So just change the port it will work fine.
Steps to change the Port.

1. Right click the icon.
2. Chose Tool
3. Change the port in Port used by MySql Section.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What option should I select?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer above:

> In my case was the Apache Service.
>
> 1. So I clicked the Wamp icon, then Apache > Service administration 'wampapache64' > Install Service.
> 2. Then again Wamp icon, then Apache > Service administration 'wampapache64' > Start Service.
> 3. And finally Wamp icon > Restart All Services.

**If Install Service is not working just open your task manager and see if apache is already running and if so, just end those processes and then follow the answer above.**

Answer (score 2):

Check if MySQL is open, close it.
Go to task manager and end process tree. Now restart wampserver. And then the MySQL (when it turns green). Hopefully it will work!
As it happens, wampserver uses the same port as MySQL, therefore, the mysql service is unable to run when MySQL is running.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this issue occurred when I first used WAMP 10 mins ago.

In case someone had the same issue as me, my solution was the following:

- Click the WAMP icon and simply *Start All Services*

[image: solution]

worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way, and very effective, is to change the port used by MySQL from 3306 to
3308.

That is, right-click on the Icon tray, go to tools, navigate to the Port used by MySQL and click on "use a port other than 3308". Click OK when the message appears.

Answer (score 0):

Open your MySQL log through the Wampserver icon in your taskbar.
It shows the error that is preventing the service from starting.
Chances are the error is due to the port being used by some other program. Now all you need to do is run MySQL on some port other than the one your computer is trying (and failing) to use. Do this by right clicking on the Wampserver icon (in your taskbar), going to MySQL and clicking on "Use a port other than __". Type in a port that is not being used by any service. Type netstat -an in your command prompt to see all the ports that are being used. Your new port should be such that it is not present here. The icon should go green now.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution after I encountered the same problem.

1. Right click on your local server
2. Go to wamp setting
3. Disable mariaDB

Answer (score 0):

I had just updated my wamp server manager to version 3.2.2
After trying [@Robbie Jackson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56727919/8265811), the report generated showed that MariaDB service was not existing[image]
so I installed the service via the wamp server panel and then started the service after and got greens!!

Answer (score 0):

First, Check your apache if working. If not, try to install the service.
In you wamp setting, Left click wamp -> Apache -> Service Administration -> Install Service.

Then try to change your Listen Port. Use this
[How to change port number for apache in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574332/how-to-change-port-number-for-apache-in-wamp)

After that restart all services.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had this issue today.
None of the above solutions worked for me, but I have managed to solve it finally.

I chose in the installer to install MySQL 5.x  and it did not work as services couldn't run.

I have reinstalled wampserver and in the installer I asked to install MySQL 8.x version.
Afterwards there was still an issue with 2 services running out of 3.

I opened services.msc and found wampapache64 and it was not running. I clicked to run it.
Afterwards I clicked on Wampserver icon and chose 'restart all services' and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Task Manager.
2. In Processes search for mysqlId.
3. After that select all mysqlId and do the end task.
4. Restart your wamp server.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several of the answers above, reinstalling wampserver64 did it, but the error came back. Finally I used **MySQL Installer - Community** to upgrade the MySQL toolset. Then I restarted wampserver64 and "wampmysqld64" stayed active, hopefully it will continue.

[image: MySQL Installer - Community]

Comment: it happened again, then this time I went to the process manager and ended MySQL process. Thanks to icyNerd: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59401765/2892791

Comment: So as likely as not you now have 2 MySQL server instances on your system

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem is to
click on the wampserver at the right hand side where you normally check your battery status and after that it will display alot of details and at the bottom you will see tools go to your tools and click on reinstaill all service and that is all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a same problem with Wamp 3.2.6 64 bit version in Windows machine. I found my Apache service was not running. I found it was the IIS service which used the 80 port, which was also default port of Wamp Apache.
I just stop the IIS service and restart the Wamp server and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

All services were stopped. Instead of changing the ports I did these steps and it worked for me.

Right click on WAMPSERVER icon -> go to **Tools** -> and then click on **Reinstall all services**.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I had a problem with a missing DLL: VCRUNTIME140.dll, during the Wampserver install. This affected one of the services. I found the solution was to install the missing dll by installing Visual C++. I had to use the 2019 version as the 2015 didn't solve the problem.

I hope that is useful.

Comment: Please add your answer as  a comment or explain more by yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Mori. What needs more explanation?